# Why do I get a KeyError when attempting to draw a scatterplot?

Tags: python, keyerror, iris-dataset

I am trying to make a simple scatterplot and get a `KeyError`.

I have tried to see if it is a matter of the feature "group" that contains the four classes, but it is not so I am not sure what is the issue here.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
iris_nparray = iris.data
iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
iris_dataframe["group"] = pd.Series([iris.target_names[k] for k in iris.target], dtype = "category")

colors_palete = {0:"red", 1:"yellow", 2:"blue"}
colors = [colors_palete[c] for c in iris_dataframe["group"]]
simple_scatterplot = iris_dataframe.plot(kind = "scatter",x="petal length (cm)", y="petal width (cm)", c =colors)
```

Expected:

`A nice colorful scatterplot`

Actual result:

````
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-818f07044064> in <module>
      1 colors_palete = {0:"red", 1:"yellow", 2:"blue"}
----> 2 colors = [colors_palete[c] for c in iris_dataframe["group"]]
      3 simple_scatterplot = iris_dataframe.plot(kind = "scatter",x="petal length (cm)", y="petal width (cm)", c =colors)

<ipython-input-128-818f07044064> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 colors_palete = {0:"red", 1:"yellow", 2:"blue"}
----> 2 colors = [colors_palete[c] for c in iris_dataframe["group"]]
      3 simple_scatterplot = iris_dataframe.plot(kind = "scatter",x="petal length (cm)", y="petal width (cm)", c =colors)

KeyError: 'setosa'```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: your colour mapping is wrongly defined.

`iris_dataframe["group"]` contains `['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']`.

Accordingly, `colors_palete` (did you mean "palette"?) should be:

```
colors_palete = {'setosa': "red", 'versicolor': "yellow", 'virginica': "blue"}
```

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was that in the example that I was examining, the class values were already 1,2 or 3 instead of "versicolor", "setosa" or "virginica".

I really appreciate your help.